# Accessing VB6.0 Resource Editor At Runtime

Tags: vb6

I was wondering if I could insert a file into resource (.RES) file during runtime instead of inserting a file using resource editor at design time. Could anyone help me with this information ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't modify the program while it is running anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, not directly. You shouldn't need to though.

You can do a kludge hack, and have users running a program that compiles another (your) program at runtime and then runs it.